# I have to write a code that gets the smallest number in an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop

Below is my code. It keeps returning 4 but the smallest value is 3. How do I get it to read 3 instead of 4?

```
public static int getMinIndex(int[]a, int index) {
    int min=a[index];
    int minIndex=index;
    for(int i=index+1;i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i]<min) {
            min=a[i];
            minIndex=i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] a={11,4,8,6,3,10};
    int min=ch7Codes.getMinIndex(a,1);
    System.out.println(min);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "you have to" write the code? Is this homework?

Comment: It's doing what you told it to do.  You are successfully returning the index of the minimum value.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you did this intentionally but you are starting from index `1`, which is the second element in the array.

Answer (score 4):

There are better ways to get the minimun of an array, but he problem in your case is the way that you are going through the array, it begins on 0 not in 1, and you are not getting back the miniimun value, you are getting back the index of the minimun value wchich in that vector is 4 corrresponding of a value of 3

```
public static int getMinIndex(int[]a, int index){
    int min=a[index];
    int minIndex=index;
    for(int i=index+1;i<a.length;i++){

        if(a[i]<min){
            min=a[i];
            minIndex=i;
        }
    }

    return min; // with this you return the minimun value
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] a={11,4,8,6,3,10};
    int min=ch7Codes.getMinIndex(a,0);
    System.out.println(min);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note when approaching this problem

- Your current method is returning the index location in the array of the smallest value. That implementation is correct.
- To return the smallest value (3 is smaller than 4) you must store the value and return the value, not the index.
- Arrays start at 0, not 1. If an array has 3 items, the indexes are {0, 1, 2}

Here's the code to return the smallest value in the array

```
public static int getMinIndex(int[]a) {
    // We'll say the first number in the array is the smallest
    int min = a[0];

    // Loop through every element. Since arrays start at 0, we -1 from length
    for(int i=0; i < a.length - 1; i++){
         // If a[i] is a smaller number, store that number
         if(a[i] < min){
             min=a[i];
          }
    }
    // Return the smallest number
    return min; 
}
```

I removed the index parameter from the method because it's not needed. Your current method returns the index of the smallest number (3 is located at index 4 of the array.) So a shortcut could also be to do

```
System.out.println(a[min]);
```